# Access parent in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a rails 3.2 application with an easy hierarchy: A user has many clients, a client has many invoices.

I want the users to only see their own clients and invoices using scopes, by doing `Client.by_user(current_user)` and `Invoice.by_user(current_user)`. For clients, I have this, which works fine:

```
scope :by_user, lambda { |user| where(user_id: user.id) }
```

However, if I try the same for invoices

```
scope :by_user, lambda { |user| where(client.user_id => user.id) }
```

it fails, telling me `undefined local variable or method 'client'`.

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to add user_ids to the invoices.

Comment: Why not just use `current_user.clients` and `current_user.invoices`? (edit: assuming that `User` `has_many :invoices, :through => :clients`)

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't recognize `invoice.user`. Will I have to add the user_id to the invoices table for that?

Comment: You shouldn't. You can do an inverse relation as well where `Invoice` `belongs_to :user, :through => :client`.

Comment: p.s. my initial suspicion is that that might be what's wrong in your scopes as well -- did you set up the inverse `belongs_to` relations on the `Client` and `Invoice` models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @gregates said in comments, better for you to define associations for User, Client & Invoice models and then use `user.clients`, `user.invoices`, `invoice.user` etc.:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :invoices, through: :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_one :user, through: :client
end
```

But if you prefer idea with scope, you should join clients table to invoices in your scope:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :by_user, lambda { |user| joins(:client).where("clients.user_id = ?", user.id) }
  ...
end
```

Comment: `belongs_to :user` on the `Invoice` model, though, will require a `user_id` foreign key, won't it? You need `through: :client`?

Comment: @gregates, as I can see in [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to), belongs_to does not have :through option.

Comment: I have implemented the above, but after creating an invoice that belongs to a client and a user, `invoice.user` gives me `nil` - how come?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I thought I had done this before, but actually we used `has_one :through`. @Charles try `has_one :user, through: :client` on your `Invoice` model.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! I have edited the answer accordingly. Thanks you two!